# How to press function key f6 using robot framework for go to the URL of the current window

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I want to copy the url of the current open window using robot framework.

Press Keys none F6

and it will lead to failed, so please tell me how to copy the url of the current open tab of browser.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score -1):

You are overcomplicating this process. As far as I know, keyword `Get Location` from SeleniumLibrary does exactly what you want to do.

See details: https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Location

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).